# Serializing JSON with class metadata

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I've used both Gson and Jackson and both of them offer a way to deal with polymorphism. For example, with Jackson you need to declare the class with a `@JsonSubTypes` and add each and every `@JsonSubTypes.Type` you have. Similar thing happens with Gson.

My question is if there is an option to make it work like with how MongoDB serializes data. It automatically adds a `_class` metadata field. With this method, you don't need to manually register every subtype you've created.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with jackson:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "_class")
public abstract class AbstractModel {
    
}

public class ModelA extends AbstractModel {
    
}
...
mapper.writeValue(System.out, new ModelA());
```

Outputs:

```json
{
  "_class" : "demo.ModelA"
}
```

This way you dont have to add json subtypes for all types you add.

Comment: Great! Do you know what's the equivalent in Gson?

Comment: I do not have experience with gson. This topic may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999278/gson-how-to-include-class-name-property-when-serializing-object-of-any-type